# Is there a way to optionally hide the title bar when logged in?

Tags: theme-development, admin-bar

When I'm creating a theme and I'm logged in, there is a wp admin bar that runs across the top of the page. This is helpful for normal use but it makes it hard to see what I'm working on when I'm making a theme. It would be helpful if there was a way to hide this.

Is there a disclosure button to hide or minimize the title bar or maybe a plugin?

Comment: Dicm has it, but also you can usually style things to allow for the admin bar. When it's visible there's a class added to the body that you can use to adjust your other styles accordingly.

Comment: OK. It looks like the identity selector is "#wpadminbar". I think I can set that selector early on with "display:none".

Comment: I didn't mean turn it off as your users may want it. I usually use the extra IDs and classes to push my content down by 32px when the bar is showing if the design in working to requires fixed or absolutely positioned elements. Non-positioned elements aren't usually a problem as WP adds margin to the HTML element to accommodate the bar anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but when you login into wp-admin and go under "Users" -> "Your profile", you have an option to hide the admin bar.

[image]